# Keras LSTM using timesteps = 1 and train_on_batch

Tags: keras, lstm

I'm using an `LSTM` to achieve a classification problem. I have a dataset composed by sentences, each sentence is composed by a variable number of words and I have to predict a label for each word of each sentence.

For example, I have a dataset of shape `(300000, 800)`, so 300000 words and each word is made of 800 features (word embeddings, etc...).
Moreover, each sentence is divided in subtrees, which each subtree is a syntactic dependency tree between words. My task is to learn the dependencies between words of a subtree.

I thought to train the network using `timesteps=1` and  the `train_on_batch` function, where the batch size is variable and equal to the subtree cardinality.

Is it a reasonable process?